# Using Command Line in Nodejs vs. API? Why one or the other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, api, command-line

Somebody writes:

> I started developing of this module when had a need to have Tesseract
>   working with Node.js. But found that existing modules do call
>   tesseract command-line tool. And I have a need in fully customizable
>   API. (from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract)

Can somebody explain to me why an API is preferable to utilising the command line tools in an application? Are there very strong reasons for one or the other, or is it more like a preference and has to do mainly with readability?

Comment: why is this getting a downvote? I find the question a perfectly valid one, and I would like to know why somebody would think it is not, rather than just downvoting it not commenting on it at all

Comment: Because an API is clearly defined, whereas just running random command lines may or may not work, depending on what you have installed, what OS you have, what permissions is the app given, what is the authentication is used and so on. Also, an API is literally designed to be consumed by programs - a commandline _may_ or may not provide program-friendly output.

Comment: You may find the question valid, but isn't really fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

An API is designed to be interacted with by code.

A command line tool is designed to be interacted with by typing on the command line.

Writing code to wrap around a command line tool means that you have to deal with escaping all the input for the command line, and to get data out of it you have to parse STDOUT and STDERR. It is more complicated and error prone.